# Generate a variable in a SQL statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to declare a variable in a SQL Oracle statement to work with it in the next lines. I write a simple statement as example:

```
SELECT customer.surname, LENGTH(customer.name) long, customer.age 
FROM customer
WHERE long > 4;
```

I didn't found any "clear" info on the web, is that even possible?

Comment: This isn't very clear either on what you want to do. Provide more information please. What is the variable type you want and what do you want assigned to it to use `in the next lines`?

Comment: `Where length(customer.name) > 4.`  The long alias (not a variable but close) is not available in the where due to [order of operation](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/70-sql-query-order-of-operations.htm).  The from, then where then select.  So first the database gets the records from customer.  Then it limits them by length of 4 then it shows the select values and calculated values.  In this order you can see the alias long wouldn't be known when the where clause is executed.

Comment: Your title indicates "VARIABLE" but in your SQL statement 'long' is an alias.  These are different concepts in SQL which leads to ambiguity in your question.  I'm assuming you mean alias and not variable.  No biggie, just wanted to make you aware of the difference; so we can eliminate ambiguity in the question.

Answer (score 2):

The order of operations for a select statement is not the same order in which it is written.

1. FROM (including joins and subqueries but then in the order of operation starts over for that subquery; like order of operations in algebra; inside out )
2. WHERE
3. GROUP BY
4. SELECT
5. HAVING
6. ORDER BY

There are some exceptions to the above as not all engines process quite this way.  It appears you may be able to use an alias in a group by if you're using mySQL.  I'm not familiar enough to know if it changes the processing or if mySQL is just looking ahead.

In this order you can see the where executes before the 'long' alias is generated, so the DB Engine doesn't know what long is at the time it's being executed.  Put another way, long is not in scope at the time the where clause is being evaluated.

This can be solved by simply repeating the calculation in the where clause or nesting queries; but the latter is less efficient.

In the below I:

- Aliased customer as c to save typing and improve readability.
- re-wrote the where clause to use the formula instead of the alias
- renamed your long alias due to [reserved/keyword](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/ap_keywd.htm) use.

.

```
SELECT c.surname, LENGTH(customer.name) as Name_Len, c.age 
FROM customer as c
WHERE LENGTH(c.name)> 4;
```

In this next example we use the `with` key word to generate a set of data called CTE (Common Table Expression) with the length of the name calculated.  This in effect changes the the order in which the where clause is processed.

In this case the FROM is processed in the CTE then the select including our calculated value but no where clause is applied.  Then a second query is run selecting from the CTE data set with the where clause.  Since the first dataset already calculated the Name_Len, we can now use it in the where clause.

```
WITH CTE AS (SELECT c.surname, LENGTH(customer.name) as Name_Len, c.age 
    FROM customer as c)
SELECT * 
FROM CTE    
WHERE Name_Len > 4;
```

This could also be done as a subquery; but after you nest a few of those, you can see using a with may make it easier to read/maintain.

```
SELECT CTE.*
FROM (SELECT c.surname, LENGTH(customer.name) as Name_Len, c.age 
      FROM customer as c) as CTE    
WHERE CTE.Name_Len > 4;
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you asked the question is incorrect though there is a solution to your problem in SQL.

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT customer.surname,
               LENGTH (customer.name) col_long,
               customer.age
          FROM customer)
 WHERE col_long > 4;
```

The sub-query here is called `in-line` view. For more details check Oracle documentation online.

Also, LONG is a reserved keyword, so either rename it or use like "long".

Answer (score 0):

Have you searched online? This is literally covered everywhere... Something like this probably;

```
DECLARE aVariable NUMBER;

BEGIN
   SELECT someColumn INTO aVariable FROM aTable;
END;
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is what they were after; but the question is ambiguous.  The title is basically your answer but the SQL presented implies something different.